# Is there an idiom for “can take truth unprettified whatever it is”?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

Here's the scenario: I screwed something and that caused some real harm. Now another person could just tell me, “Dude, you screwed X and this caused this and this harm," but instead he will try to be supe- diplomatic and vague to “not hurt my feelings.”

I’d like to tell him, “Dude, stop that diplomacy and prettification — I can take the ugly truth, whatever it is.”

Is there a widely recognized idiom for conveying that message?

Comment: The phrase 'warts and all' conveys a similar concept.

Comment: The customary orthographic conventions of English derivational morphology lead not to **prettyfication*, but rather to *prettification*.

Answer (score 13):

"Tell (or Give) it to me straight".

Comment: +1 Some other options: *don't beat around the bush*, *no need to sugarcoat it* and *tell it [to me] like it is*.

Comment: often followed by 'Doc'.

Comment: often followed by *, Doc - how long have I got?*

Comment: @onomato: I'm flagging your comment as *should be an answer* :p

Comment: Also, *let's not mince words*.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

> Just give me the unvarnished truth, please.

(This is admittedly used more in written communication.)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could deny being *thin-skinned* (or assert that you are *thick-skinned*).

Answer (score 0):

- **Be honest.**

Or, a little less tersely:

- **Be honest with me.**